# How to pass value from @Value in service from another service?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a interface witch use a variable *tableName*

```
public interface TableNameService {
    void printName();
}

@Serive
public class TableNameServiceImpl implements TableNameService{
     @Ovveride
     public void printName() {
          System.out.println(tableName);
     }
}
```

This interface I inject to other services like OracleService etc and initialize *tableName* in services through @Value.
For example:

```
@Service
public class OracleService {
     private TableNameService service; 
     @Value("${tableName}")
     private String tableName;

    public void print() {
         service.printName()
    }
}
```

How to pass field from OracleService to TableNameService during injection TableNameServiceImpl so as not to pass it in the method parameters and not to put it down all the time with your hands?

Comment: you can add a parameter in the `printName` method to accept table name

Comment: `tableName` is unknown  in `printName()`. By the code for now, no need for injection of TableName in OracleService. You can just implement TableNameService in OracleService

Answer (score 0):

A common reason why dependency injection became so popular is because it avoids boilerplate code where you need to pass from one method into the other the same instances and values.

In your case here you could also take advantage of DI by adding `@Value("${tableName}") private String tableName;` in your `TableNameServiceImpl` class and autowiring this `service` class inside `OracleService`.

```
@Service
public class TableNameServiceImpl implements TableNameService{

     @Value("${tableName}") 
     private String tableName;

     @Ovveride
     public void printName() {
          System.out.println(tableName);
     }
}
```

And then you can have

```
    @Service
    public class OracleService {
 
         @Autowired
         private TableNameService service; 
         
        public void print() {
             service.printName()
        }
    }
```